# extension Optional where Wrapped works in one app, but not another (both Swift 5 set)

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, swift5

The line of code
`extension Optional where Wrapped` works in one of my apps, but the same code in another throws "Use of undeclared type 'Wrapped'"

The context is that this line of code is used as part of a buddle of code to allow for kotlin style .orEmpty or .orZero in preference to the use of the nil coalescing operator such as `if someInteger ?? 0 > 0` should be able to become `if someInteger.orZero > 0`

I checked the project settings and found both apps were set to use Swift 5, I attempted to match all the other project settings to the app where the extension works.

```swift
extension Optional where Wrapped: CollectionDefaultValue {
    var orEmpty: Wrapped { return self ?? Wrapped.orEmpty }
}
```

This should see the `Wrapped` version of `Optional` from the Swift bundle. It work in one app, but in the other each line is flagged with the error "Use of undeclared type 'Wrapped'"

Comment: What's `CollectionDefaultValue`? It seems like a custom type, are you sure you declared it in both projects?

Comment: Try changing its declaration to `public`

Comment: Does the other project somehow redefine `Optional`?

Comment: Seems like there was a conflict in the type system causing this, perhaps with some type called Optional having been defined in an Objective-C library... The fix was to specify where Optional was coming from...   extension Swift.Optional where Wrapped: CollectionDefaultValue {
    var orEmpty: Wrapped { return self ?? Wrapped.orEmpty }
}